# Can't form mpi ring

Tags: mpi

I am facing problem in configuring and running MPI on my systems.

Here is what I tried:

1) I ran 'mpd &' on one machine and then I ran 'mpdtrace -l' on the same machine. I got this as output: "my-lappy_53430 (127.0.1.1)"
2) On another machine I ran 'mpd -h  -p 53430 &' and got this error:

```
akshey-desktop_39993: conn error in connect_lhs: Connection timed out  
akshey-desktop_39993 (connect_lhs 924): failed to connect to lhs at 10.2.28.137 52430  
akshey-desktop_39993 (enter_ring 879): lhs connect failed  
akshey-desktop_39993 (run 267): failed to enter ring
```

Can you please help with this issue? I tried to ping and ssh the first machine(on which mpd is running) from the second machine and it worked.

After this I executed 'mpdheck' on the first machine, I got this output:

```
* * * first ipaddr for this host (via my-lappy) is: 127.0.1.1
```

These are the contents of /etc/hosts of the first machine:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   my-lappy

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Then I ran 'mpdcheck -l' and got this as output:

```
    **********  
    Your unqualified hostname resolves to 127.0.0.1, which is  
    the IP address reserved for localhost. This likely means that  
    you have a line similar to this one in your /etc/hosts file:  
    127.0.0.1   $uqhn  
    This should perhaps be changed to the following:  
    127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost  
    **********
```

Even after changing the first line of /etc/hosts to "127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost" I still got the same output from 'mpdcheck -l'

Please note that I do not have access to the DNS server of the network and these machines do not have a DNS entry in the DNS server. (I think this should not be a problem because we can always use IP addresses instead of hostnames. Isn't it so?)

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

1. You probably don't want to wire up an MPD ring by hand.  Unless you are just doing some troubleshooting with a raw `mpd` command, you probably want to use `mpdboot`.  Its usage is described in the [User's Guide](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/documentation/files/mpich2-1.3-userguide.pdf).
2. Since you are using MPD, you are using MPICH2 or an MPICH2 derivative.  Starting with MPICH2 1.1 there is a new process manager available, called "[hydra](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager)".  I encourage you to update to the latest version of MPICH2 that you can and give hydra a try.  It is much more robust than MPD and has many more features, including better performance.

Answer (score 0):

from my personal and recent experience, I would say that

```
127.0.1.1   my-lappy
```

must be change to you LAN address, and match your `hostname`. You can change it with `hostname <new hostname>` and/or edit *permanently* `/etc/hostname`.

Then on `host1` you need to start `mpd --echo` and note the port on which `mpd` will listen:

```
mpd_port=N
```

then on `host2` start:

```
mpd --host=host1 --port=N
```

It's very important that the `/etc/hosts` files of all the machines resolve correctly the names to the IPs.

`mpdtrace -l` will confirm that the ring is correctly setup.

Answer (score 0):

Check for firewall on your systems that might be blocking the default ports. Turn off the firewall by turning off the ipchains and iptables to test if that is the problem.

In addition, make sure the hostnames/IP addresses are correct and can be successfully resolved.